# How to storage values in local storage using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can dynamic values be stored in the local storage?

I have a seat layout. How i can store only the selected seat numbers in the local storage, but not reserved seats?

My code can be seen below:

```js
$(function() {
  var settings = {
    rows: 6,
    cols: 10,
    rowCssPrefix: 'row-',
    colCssPrefix: 'col-',
    seatWidth: 35,
    seatHeight: 35,
    seatCss: 'seat',
    selectedSeatCss: 'selectedSeat',
    selectingSeatCss: 'selectingSeat'
  };

  var init = function(reservedSeat) {
    var str = [],
      seatNo, className;
    for (i = 0; i < settings.rows; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < settings.cols; j++) {
        seatNo = (i + j * settings.rows + 1);
        className = settings.seatCss + ' ' + settings.rowCssPrefix + i.toString() + ' ' + settings.colCssPrefix + j.toString();
        if ($.isArray(reservedSeat) && $.inArray(seatNo, reservedSeat) != -1) {
          className += ' ' + settings.selectedSeatCss;
        }
        str.push('<li class="' + className + '"' +
          'style="top:' + (i * settings.seatHeight).toString() + 'px;left:' + (j * settings.seatWidth).toString() + 'px">' +
          '<a title="' + seatNo + '">' + seatNo + '</a>' +
          '</li>');
      }
    }
    $('#place').html(str.join(''));
    var SeatNo = document.getElementById('place').value;
    localStorage.setItem('SeatNum', SeatNo);
  };

  //case I: Show from starting
  //init();

  //Case II: If already booked
  var bookedSeats = [5, 10, 25];
  init(bookedSeats);


  $('.' + settings.seatCss).click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass(settings.selectedSeatCss)) {
      alert('This seat is already reserved');
    } else {
      $(this).toggleClass(settings.selectingSeatCss);
    }
  });

  $('#btnShow').click(function() {
    var str = [];
    $.each($('#place li.' + settings.selectedSeatCss + ' a, #place li.' + settings.selectingSeatCss + ' a'), function(index, value) {
      str.push($(this).attr('title'));
    });
    alert(str.join(','));
  })

  $('#btnShowNew').click(function() {
    var str = [],
      item;
    $.each($('#place li.' + settings.selectingSeatCss + ' a'), function(index, value) {
      item = $(this).attr('title');
      str.push(item);
    });
    alert(str.join(','));
  })
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="holder">
    <ul id="place">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="">
    <ul id="seatDescription">
      <li style="background:url('available_seat_img.gif') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;">Available Seat</li>
      <li style="background:url('booked_seat_img.gif') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;">Booked Seat</li>
      <li style="background:url('selected_seat_img.gif') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;">Selected Seat</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="width:100%">
    <input type="button" id="btnShowNew" value="Show Selected Seats" />
    <input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Show All" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are we supposed to see in your code? You’re using `localStorage.setItem('SeatNum', SeatNo);`. What exactly isn’t working with it?

Comment: not working it's is getting error@Xufox

Comment: What error? What isn’t working?

Comment: i can update  with code can see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ebpohhyz/1/

Answer (score 1):

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is an object within the global 'window' object, and therefore will normally be available throughout your javascript code. It pretty much behaves like a dictionary, you create, retrieve, edit and remove key:value pairs. jQuery will not be necessary.

It is also imporant to remember that localStorage only support string values, and simply saving an array would not work.

```
// When modifying bookedSeats:
var bookedSeatsCacheString = JSON.stringify(bookedSeats);
localStorage.setItem('bookedSeats', bookedSeatsCacheString);


// Init code:
var bookedSeatsCache = localStorage.getItem('bookedSeats');
var bookedSeats = JSON.parse(bookedSeatsCache);
if(!Array.isArray(bookSeats))
  bookedSeats = [];
init(bookedSeats);
```

EDIT: I edited your code to make this work with localStorage

```js
$(function () {
    var settings = {
        rows: 6,
        cols: 10,
        rowCssPrefix: 'row-',
        colCssPrefix: 'col-',
        seatWidth: 35,
        seatHeight: 35,
        seatCss: 'seat',
        selectedSeatCss: 'selectedSeat',
        selectingSeatCss: 'selectingSeat'
    };

    var init = function (reservedSeat) {
        var str = [], seatNo, className;
            for (i = 0; i < settings.rows; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < settings.cols; j++) {
                    seatNo = (i + j * settings.rows + 1);
                    className = settings.seatCss + ' ' + settings.rowCssPrefix + i.toString() + ' ' + settings.colCssPrefix + j.toString();
                    if ($.isArray(reservedSeat) && $.inArray(seatNo, reservedSeat) != -1) {
                        className += ' ' + settings.selectedSeatCss;
                    }
                    str.push('<li class="' + className + '"' +
                        'style="top:' + (i * settings.seatHeight).toString() + 'px;left:' + (j * settings.seatWidth).toString() + 'px">' +
                        '<a title="' + seatNo + '">' + seatNo + '</a>' +
                        '</li>');
                }
            }
        $('#place').html(str.join(''));
    };

    // Init code
    var bookedSeatsCache = localStorage.getItem('bookedSeats'),
        bookedSeats;
        
    if(typeof bookedSeatsCache === 'string' && bookedSeatsCache.length > 0)
      bookedSeats = JSON.parse(bookedSeatsCache);
    else
      bookedSeats = [];
      
    init(bookedSeats);


    $('.' + settings.seatCss).click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass(settings.selectedSeatCss)){
          alert('This seat is already reserved');
        }
        else{
          var seatNum = $(this).attr('title');
          bookedSeats.push(seatNum);
          localStorage.setItem('bookedSeats', JSON.stringify(bookedSeats));
          $(this).toggleClass(settings.selectingSeatCss);
        }
    });

    $('#btnShow').click(function () {
        var str = [];
        $.each($('#place li.' + settings.selectedSeatCss + ' a, #place li.'+ settings.selectingSeatCss + ' a'), function (index, value) {
            str.push($(this).attr('title'));
        });
        alert(str.join(','));
    })

    $('#btnShowNew').click(function () {
        var str = [], item;
        $.each($('#place li.' + settings.selectingSeatCss + ' a'), function (index, value) {
            item = $(this).attr('title');                   
            str.push(item);                   
        });
        alert(str.join(','));
    })
});
```

```css
#holder{    
height:225px;    
width:365px;
background-color:#F5F5F5;
border:1px solid #A4A4A4;
margin-left:10px;   
}
#place {
position:relative;
margin:7px;
}
#place a{
font-size:0.6em;
}
#place li
{
 list-style: none outside none;
 position: absolute;   
}    
#place li:hover
{
background-color:yellow;      
} 
#place .seat{
background:url("available_seat_img.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
height:33px;
width:33px;
display:block;
padding:5px;   
}
#place .selectedSeat
{ 
background-image:url("booked_seat_img.gif");          
}
#place .selectingSeat
{ 
background-image:url("selected_seat_img.gif");        
}
#place .row-3, #place .row-4{
margin-top:10px;
}
#seatDescription li{
vertical-align: middle;    
list-style: none outside none;
color:white;
font-family:'LatoWeb', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
padding-left:28px;
padding-top:14px;
height:35px;
float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="holder">
    <ul id="place">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="">
    <ul id="seatDescription">
      <li style="background:url('available_seat_img.gif') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;">Available Seat</li>
      <li style="background:url('booked_seat_img.gif') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;">Booked Seat</li>
      <li style="background:url('selected_seat_img.gif') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;">Selected Seat</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="width:100%">
    <input type="button" id="btnShowNew" value="Show Selected Seats" />
    <input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Show All" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can Please   update in my code there is so mush confusing  @fingeron

Comment: I need to understand what's this:

`var SeatNo = document.getElementById('place').value; localStorage.setItem('SeatNum', SeatNo);`

Comment: @DSP I added a code snippet for you to try. All I did was initially taking the value from localStorage, and then editing the localStorage value every time a seat is added. Notice that you will have to do the reverse action (removing from array and updating localStorage) when a seat is not selected anymore.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: bookSeats is not defined@ fingeron

Comment: My bad, looks like a typo. Fix it to 'bookedSeats' @DSP

Comment: I am sorry for asking getting another error  Uncaught TypeError: JSON.strinfify is not a function

Comment: sorry it is spelling mistake @fingeron

Comment: It is null in the beginning, but once you select a chair the code will update `bookedSeats` and will set the localStorage accordingly. If you want to initialize localStorage with a value, use `localStorage.setItem('bookedSeats', JSON.stringify([SEATS]));`

Comment: getting error Uncaught ReferenceError: booketSeatsCache is not defined@fingeron

Comment: whenever i selecting seat local storage bookedSeats array shows [null]@fingeron